# Solving $\frac{x^2 + k^2 - 2xk}{x^2 + c^2 - 2xc} = e^{-2yg}\frac{k^2}{c^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$\frac{x^2 + k^2 - 2xk}{x^2 + c^2 - 2xc} = e^{-2yg}\frac{k^2}{c^2}$$

I am attempting to solve for $x$. I've been at it for a while and have reached to above equation, but now it seems to get quite messy. Any help?

Important:

$k = \frac{a+g}{2E}$,

$c = \frac{a-g}{2E}$,

$g = \sqrt{a^2 + 4E}$.

What has yet to be defined are just real constants (i.e, $E$, $a$, $y$)

Answer (score 2):

It helps to note that everything is pretty much a constant, hence we may reduce as follows:

$$\frac{x^2-2kx+k^2}{x^2-2cx+c^2}=P$$

where $P=e^{-2yg}\frac{k^2}{c^2}$.  Then notice some perfect squares:

$$x^2-2kx+k^2=(x-k)^2\\x^2-2cx+c^2=(x-c)^2$$

Thus, the problem further reduces:

$$\frac{x-k}{x-c}=\pm\sqrt P$$

Multiply both sides by $x-c$ to get

$$x-k=\pm\sqrt P(x-c)$$

$$\mp c\sqrt P-k=(\pm\sqrt P-1)x$$

> $$x=\frac{\mp c\sqrt P-k}{\pm\sqrt P-1}$$

(watch the signs, as $\pm$ is always the opposite sign of $\mp$)

Comment: How did I not notice those perfect squares? Haha. What's wrong with me.... Thanks! Will accept answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: @ImeanH Now, if those weren't perfect squares, then you ought've skipped that step, multiplying both sides by the denominator and solving the resulting quadratic by using the quadratic formula.